# Polynomial with icosahedral symmetry

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups

I am interested in polynomials with icosahedral symmetry.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0955.pdf

says that

$$
p(v,w)=v^{11}w+11v^6w^6-vw^{11}
$$

has icosahedral symmetry. Each term is homogeneous of degree $12$. Moreover, within each term the power of $v$ and the power of $w$ are congruent mod $ 5 $. That implies $ p $ is invariant under the following generator of the binary icosahedral subgroup of $ SU_2 $
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}} & 0\\
0 & e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{5}} 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\zeta_5 & 0\\
0 & \overline{\zeta_5}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In other words, the symmetry
\begin{align*}
v \mapsto \zeta_5 v \\
w \mapsto \overline{\zeta_5} w
\end{align*}
fixes $ p $. Apparently $ p $ is also invariant under
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\zeta_5+\overline{\zeta_5} & \zeta_5^2-\overline{\zeta_5}^2\\
\zeta_5^2-\overline{\zeta_5}^2 & \zeta_5-\overline{\zeta_5} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and these two matrices generate the entire 120 element binary icosahedral subgroup $ 2I \cong SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5) $  of $ SU_2 $.

Are there any lower degree polynomials in two complex variables $ v,w $ with icosahedral symmetry? How about polynomials in three real variables $ x,y,z $ that are invariant with respect to the icosahedral subgroup $ I \cong A_5 \cong PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5) $ of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no invariants of smaller degree.

Let $G = PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$. Assuming that you are working over a field of characteristic $0$ (in fact, it would be enough to work over a field of characteristic not dividing $\# G$), it is a theorem of Klein, proved in his book on the Icosahedron, that the invariant ring $K[v,w]^G$ is generated by the polynomials
\begin{gather*}
v^{11} w - 11v^6w^6 - vw^{11}\\
v^{20} + 228 v^{15} w^5 + 494 v^{10} w^{10} - 228 v^5 w^{15} + w^{20} \\
v^{30} - 522 v^{25} w^5 - 10005 v^{20} w^{10} - 10005 v^{10} w^{20} + 522 v^5 w^{25} + w^{30}
\end{gather*}

This can be proved by computing the Poincare series using Molien's formula (or by computer algebra e.g., Magma's `FundamentalInvariants`).

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I wanted! Is there any similar result for the case of $ G=PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5) $ and the invariant ring  $ \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]^G $? Also two minor questions: is there a reason you wrote the icosahedral group $ PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5) $ in your question when the action seems to be associated to $ SU_2 $ and the binary icosahedral group $ SL_2(\mathbb{F}_5) $? Also the reference I looked at had a positive sign in front of the $ 11v^6w^6 $ while your answer has a negative sign. Is that difference significant?

Comment: The difference in the sign comes from me accidentally swapping the roles of $v$ and $w$ (then taking $-p$) - I should have followed your convention, sorry. Writing $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ was a mistake, it came from the fact I was thinking geometrically (about the action on $\mathbb{P}^1$) when I wrote this answer, in this context $-I$ acts trivially.

Comment: Certainally there will be a similar result for the action on $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, since Hilbert-Noether showed that the invariants are a finitely generated $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. One can work it out once you have an explicit representation of your group - the book of Benson "Polynomial Invariants of Finite Groups" is a good reference.

Comment: My representation is just the standard representation of $ SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ acting in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ (really the restriction of that action to the icosahedral subgroup). Thanks for the reference I'll look into it!

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira indeed, but if you want explicit invariants then you need to choose your $A_5$ subgroup - not just up to conjugation. If I'm right I think the algebra generators should be in degrees $2, 6, 10, 15$ with some syzygy.  If you can get a matrix group $H \subset SO_3(K) \subset GL_3(K) \cap SO_3$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a subfield, then you can use the magma functions ```P<u,v,w> := PolynomialRing(K, 3); G := GL(3, K); H := sub<G | [put generators here]>;  R := InvariantRing(H, P);  FundamentalInvariants(R);```.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for this code! I think I actually found the polynomials I was looking for on page 36 of this reference http://www.math.utah.edu/~goller/MathDocs/GollerThesisFinal.pdf But that code could definitely be useful for other questions I have in the future!

Comment: If you work with the larger group of all symmetries of the icosahedron, including the orientation reversing ones, then the ring of invariants is a polynomial ring. (The ring of invariants for any reflection group is a polynomial ring.) The degrees of the generators for this reflection group are $2$, $6$ and $10$. The additional generator  in degree $15$ should be the product of the $15$ hyperplanes which contain a pair of antipodal edges of the icosahedron.